# Better way of computing probabilities?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, for-loop, repeat

All right. The assignment I'm working on is making a game fair by changing the payout for winning the game.
To verify that the game is now more fair, I have several instances of the same code in the same program. This is because the code makes use of the random module, and by printing each of those segments I'll get different output, even though its the same code.
The only difference is the name of the functions.

Now, I'm wondering: Is there a better way to do this? It's very ugly with the same function repeated over and over, and it makes the code consist of way to many lines.

I'm fairly new to this, and would really appreciate some help making my code more efficient, and shorter.

You can see past every aspect of my code, aside from the `balance_sumdiceX(N, r)` functions and the repeated `print` statements.
I've provided pictures of the code here:

[First section of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GZsx.png)

[Second section of code, mainly print statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KmxI.png)

Comment: post your code with correct formatting in your question not as a picture

Comment: might better belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you just want to make it more efficient

Comment: Correct me if wrong, aren't all your methods the same thing? What is stopping you from just using one of the method everytime?

Comment: When code begins to repeat, especially outputs, strings, etc, usually calling a function and passing parameters specific to each output suffices to clean things up.

Comment: You don't need to define the same method multiple times to get it to return different values. Just define the method once and call it multiple times. [Example](http://ideone.com/1IHpBN)

Comment: The thing is I'm quite inexperienced with programming. I'm new to learning it.

You're asking "why do you do this? Just do that"
The problem is, I don't know how to do that. That's what I'm asking for help with.

I tried copy/pasting the code in, since it's a huge code. Didn't format correctly by itself, and since it's huge I thought it easier to use pictures.
Didn't know it was looked down upon or less convenient for you guys.

I appreciate your feedback though. I now know more about what not to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of functions is to allow code reuse. Why not put all those function calls in a loop.

```
for trial in xrange(num_trials):     # replace with the number of trials you want
    print 'After playing the game %d times, your balance will be %d' % (N, balance_sumdice(N, r))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define different methods that do the same thing, just use one

```
from random import randint
import sys

def balance_sumdice(N, r):
    w = 100
    for reps in xrange(N):
        s = 0
        for dice in xrange(4):
            outcome = randint(1,6)
            s += outcome
        if s < 9:
            w += r-1
        else:
            w -= 1
    return w

def prob_sumdice(N):
    M = 0
    for reps in xrange(N):
        s = 0
        for dice in xrange(4):
            outcome = randint(1,6)
            s += outcome
        if s < 9:
            M += 1
    return float(M)/N

N = int(sys.argv[1])
r = float(sys.argv[2])

PW = 100*prob_sumdice(N)
PL = 100 - PW

print 'Your chance of winning is %.1f, aka the chance of losing is %.1f' % (PW,PL)
for x in range(1,10):
    print 'After playing the game %d times, your balance will be %d' % (N, balance_sumdice(N,r))
```

Comment: I wanted do have several outputs, in order to show that the game is indeed more fair this time. I know I can run the program several times and record the outputs, but I was wondering whether there was a way to do what I did, without as much code.

Comment: @JonasNorill You do not have to run the program several times, just use a loop.